# Error when lowering api level from 21 to 19

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I have done some searching around and it seems people having my issue are usually when moving from api level 11-14 or so. I have got my app working 100% at api level 21 and am trying to lower it to 19.

I added

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

to my gradle, and swapped my class to extend SupportActionBar.

However, when I run my app on a kitkat device I get

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
```

This is the relevant XML file:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.xxx.toolbox.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

EDIT: As commonwares pointed out, It is probably this xml file throwing the error. Many thanks.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_semi_transparent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/CuriousBlue"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Comment: "This is the relevant XML file" -- since there is no `ListView` in that file, let alone in the first line, I suspect that you have the wrong file.

Comment: Thanks you're probably right. Added another file.

Comment: Next, we would need to see the complete stack trace, not just the error line.